# Can't Run Flutter Project Exited (sigterm)

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

Hello When I run Flutter Project on visual Studio code it doesn't run
its show me the error in this pic
this Error Because I used scoped_model packeg

When I remove the package from yaml
scoped_model: ^1.1.0
the project  run
when I use it it doesn't run and show this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

[image]

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get` after adding the package?

Comment: yes I did  it  and it still not working

Comment: And the build fails even if all you do is add the package? (also thanks for downloading Coffeed lolol)

Comment: yes the build it always fails  if I remove this package the build is run  , I'm really upset

Answer (score 1):

`Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'` errors usually occur when the packages used are not "installed" correctly. If running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` doesn't work, delete **pubspec.lock** then run `flutter pub get` to re-download the packages configured in the project.